# What environment to use for executing an unknown process in a secure and controlled way?

Tags: security, process, containers, virtual-machine, ipc

I am creating a service which runs customer binaries. The binaries can't be trusted. How can I execute them in a secure manner, along with control on the resources(RAM, CPU etc.) they use?

Comment: While it might not be perfect, have you considered something like a Cuckoo sandbox? Or maybe an online service like hybrid-analysis?

Comment: Thanks @Carlson. Maybe, I was unclear, hence edited the description. I am trying to build a service which can take my customer's code/binary and run it there.

Comment: Hi, I think if that is your goal you might want to consider using a virtual machine to spin up an instance where your customer can upload and run their binary. That being said, some types of malware look for virtualized environments and might try to break out onto your server.

Comment: I tried that at some theoretical level. I agree this is the best security that can be provided. Please correct me if I am wrong. That being said, another target of my service is to provide an independent pool of resources(CPU, RAM etc.) to the binaries, so that every one can utilise it at their peak without interfering with one another. Is there any good VM infra I can use which can manage this?

Comment: I would recommend looking at VMware's line of products. I think if you want to give an independent pool of CPU's, it would be giving each VM a certain number of VCPU and VRam. For example if you look in the settings of a VM you can allocate number of VCPU/Ram etc. That being said I believe the VM's would still share the underlying hardware of the physical machine.